# Asimov's Foundation Comic/Manga

Tags: isaac-asimov, foundation

Is there any `Comic/Manga` or `animation` adaptation of the **Asimov foundation** trilogy ?

Comment: It's not Foundation but it's Asimovs work. The comic is of his short story "The last question" which I found awesome. Not quite what you asked but it's a fun read. http://imgur.com/gallery/9KWrH

Comment: Cool, I'll make sure to check it asap, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly to say, there are no official Comics or Mangas found about the Foundation Storyline by Isaac Asimov. The only things I could find were a Marvel Comic Series about the Fantastic Four, where Mr. Fantastic revealed a Foundation after he read the Foundation Series and an Adaption of the first Chapter by Jonathon Dalton as a Comic.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_series#Impact_in_fiction_and_entertainment

http://www.jonathondalton.com/?p=12

Comment: Thanks for the Jonathon Dalton Comic. I'm just curious why it wasn't adapted yet for animation or even a movie/TVSerie ? Licensing problem ?

Comment: The Licence for a Movie is existing, but I think that no one dares to make anything about it, because it is so much Story, where you couldn't (in my opinion) cut anything out to make a film. I hope, they will do anything with the Foundation, they managed to do some great Movies from the Robot Stories (i.e. I,Robot; Bicentennial Man; A.I.)

Comment: I hope too, __in my living__ though ^^, Thx for your time :)

Comment: Lets hope together! :)

Comment: @souichiro I hope you're being sarcastic. "I, Robot" was action-oriented garbage. And that's the problem with Asimov: his stories are not truly action oriented. What would Hollywood do in order to adapt Foundation? I **shudder** at the thought.

Comment: @AndresF. The action was not part of the original stories, I know, but the message behind was great, even in this movie. You are right that I, Robot was all around garbage, but the message was delivered and that is all that counts in my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a company called SideLaunch, and their subsidiary, The Seldon Project, who are working on adapting the original Foundation trilogy into Japanese comicbooks.

https://www.sideranch.co.jp/gingateikoku

Comment: Hi there! This site appears to be entirely in Japanese and not everyone can read Japanese here. Could you [edit] in a bit more info as to what are their plans, what _Foundation_ books they're tackling etc? :)

Answer (score -3):

There was a story in the 2099 line (Spider-Man 2099 iirc) where an enemy uses psychohistory as a weapon.

Comment: Using one element in one story arc of a comic is hardly an adaptation of the Foundation trilogy. Also, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychohistory_%28fictional%29), it's Ghost Rider 2099.

Comment: GR2099. It's been awhile since I've read the books.
Agreed that it's not an adaptation of the Foundation series, but as mentioned before there has not been any graphic adaptation of the books. Just mentioning elements that have been borrowed.

Answer (score -4):

Hicham, Souichiro,

There is a "real life" recapitulation of the Asimoc Foundation Hexalogy underway, by: "Foundation Encyclopedia Dialectica [F.E.D.]".

They have derived a set of seven 'Psychohistorical-Dialectical Equations", using the "contra-Boolean Algebra" that their founder discovered, and axiomatized. --

http://www.dialectics.org/dialectics/Aoristoss_Blog/Entries/2012/5/19_The_F.E.D._Psychohistorical_Equations.html

However, although it is clear that they support and intend the use of "Big Data", their initial version of "the psychohistorical equations" are rooted in a different approach than mere statistics and probability theory.

Their initial equations are aimed at establishing a generalized, deterministic, necessary order-of-appearance, or order-of-progression, of "socio-ontology", an undergirding, causal "chain of socio-historical phenomena", around which "Big Data" can supply detailed, quantitative specifics.

For more about this, see --

http://www.dialectics.org/dialectics/Welcome.html

Regards,

M.D.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all - the questioner is not asking about "real world applications"